# MVVM Light toolkit Interaction.Triggers does not fire in datatemplate

Tags: mvvm-light

I can use Interaction.Triggers to catch the textchanged event on a textbox like so:

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextChanged}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
```

However when I use it in a datatemplate for a listview celltemplate as follows:

```
 <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding LangaugeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLangauge}" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="11">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                                                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextChanged}" />
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        </TextBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView> 
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

the event will not trigger.

Does anyone know why this does not trigger and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are in a DataTemplate, the DataContext might not be what you expect. Typically the DataContext in a DataTemplate is set to the item that the DataTemplate represents. If your TextChanged command is on the "main viewmodel" instead of the data item, you need to be more precise in the way that you specify the data binding, for example:

Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.TextChanged}"

You can see the issue when you run the code in debug mode (F5) in Studio and observe the Output window. A Data Error will be shown if the DataContext is incorrectly set.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Ok. I can see certainly see the issue in the Output window and the snippet you provided has fixed the issue. Thanks LBugnion

Answer (score 0):

It seems something handles the event before the TextBox. Maybe you could listen to Title property (collection) changed inside you ViewModel, because anyway you are calling TextChanged on ViewModel inside the trigger, I suppose.

Btw I think you're missing TwoWay mode in your binding expression.

Hope this helps.